# access to a directory in the Windows Command

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to convert a program written in python into an exe. I am using PyInstaller.
I have already installed PyInstaller with pip. But to execute it I have to type the path where PyInstaller is in the Windows Command. The point is that I am unable to reach the correct folder.
The folder I have to access to is C:\Python27\Scripts.

The Windows Command starts with C:\Users\pablo  (my name is pablo)

If I just write C:\Python27\Scripts in the Windows Command. It says to me that "C:\Python27\Scripts" is not recognize as a internal o external command...

I think the question should be very easy but I am unable to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your current directory by typing

```
cd C:\Python27\Scripts
```

And if your current directory is on a drive different from `C:`, then you need to type `C:` first.